# Cómo mostrar todos los datos de una tabla almacenada en una base de datos MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, crud, blob

Estoy intentando mostrar los datos de una tabla que contiene una imagen en formato blob, pero sólo consigo que se muestre el último registro insertado.
Me gustaría mostrar todos los registros con sus respectivas imágenes, y que al añadir un nuevo registro se mostrase con el resto de datos de la tabla.

MYSQL

noticias: idNoticia(PK), idUser(FK), titulo, imagen(LONGBLOB), texto, fecha

PHP - insertarNoticias.php (inserta los datos en la tabla noticias)

```
include('./DB.php');
session_start();

$idUser = $_SESSION['usuario'][0];
   $titulo = $_POST['titulo-noticia'];
   $texto = $_POST['texto-noticia'];
   $fecha = $_POST['fecha-noticia'];
   $nombreImagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
   $carpetaDestino = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/masterD/trabajo_final_php/img/'; 
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpetaDestino . $nombreImagen);
   
   $conexion = DB::conn();
   $imagen = fopen($carpetaDestino . $nombreImagen, "r");
   $archivoBytes = fread($imagen, intval(filesize($carpetaDestino . $nombreImagen)));
   fclose($imagen);
   
   $sentencia = 'INSERT INTO noticias (idUser, titulo, imagen, texto, fecha) VALUES (:idUser, :titulo, :imagen, :texto, :fecha)';
   $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);
   $consulta->bindParam(':idUser', $idUser);
   $consulta->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
   $consulta->bindParam(':imagen', $archivoBytes);
   $consulta->bindParam(':texto', $texto);
   $consulta->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha);
   $consulta->execute();
   $consulta->closeCursor();
   $conexion = null;
```

PHP - mostrarNoticias.php (muestra los datos de la tabla noticia)

```
include('./DB.php');
session_start();

$titulo = '';
    $imagen = '';
    $texto = '';
    $fecha = '';

    $conexion = DB::conn();
    $sentencia = 'SELECT * FROM noticias';
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);
    $consulta->execute();

    
    while ($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        
        $titulo = $row['titulo'];
        $imagen = $row['imagen'];
        $texto = $row['texto'];
        $fecha = $row['fecha'];
        
    }

    $consulta->closeCursor();
    $conexion = null;
```

PHP - adminNoticias.php (formulario)

```
<?php
include('./mostrarNoticias.php');
?>

<form class="form" action="./insertarNoticias.php" method="post" id="crear-noticia" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-label">
                                <input type="file" name="imagen" class="form-control mb-3" id="imagen-noticia" required>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="titulo-noticia" id="titulo-noticia" placeholder="Título noticia" required>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="texto-noticia" id="texto-noticia" placeholder="Texto noticia" required>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control mb-3" name="fecha-noticia" id="fecha-noticia" required>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-12 text-center">
                                Crear noticia
                            </button>
                        </form>

<div class="grid-container pt-4" id="ver-noticias">
            <div class="grid-item">
                <?php
                echo "<h4>$titulo</h4>";
                echo "<p>$texto</p>";
                echo "<p>$fecha</p>";
                echo "<img width='300' height='160' src='data:image/png; base64," . base64_encode($imagen) . "'>";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Pero en `mostrarNoticias.php` no se ve ni el intento de mostrar algo, ¿Cómo es que se sólo se muestra el último registro?.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2):

Estás haciendo este `while()` en *mostrarNoticias.php*:

```
while ($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
    $imagen = $row['imagen'];
    $texto = $row['texto'];
    $fecha = $row['fecha'];
}
```

Básicamente, este bucle modifica una y otra vez las mismas variables, por lo que cuando acaba de ejecutarse, las cuatro variables optienen el valor de la última fila, obviando todas las demás.

Luego, en *adminNoticias.php* no ejecutas ningún bucle que recorra cada línea, por eso solo se muestra una única fila con las variables que guardaste en *mostrarNoticias.php*:

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <?php
        echo "<h4>$titulo</h4>";
        echo "<p>$texto</p>";
        echo "<p>$fecha</p>";
        echo "<img width='300' height='160' src='data:image/png; base64," . base64_encode($imagen) . "'>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Una solución posible está en prescindir del archivo *mostrarNoticias.php* para incluir el bucle `while()` directamente en *adminNoticias.php*:

```
<form class="form" action="./insertarNoticias.php" method="post" id="crear-noticia" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-label">
        <input type="file" name="imagen" class="form-control mb-3" id="imagen-noticia" required>
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="titulo-noticia" id="titulo-noticia" placeholder="Título noticia" required>
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="texto-noticia" id="texto-noticia" placeholder="Texto noticia" required>
        <input type="date" class="form-control mb-3" name="fecha-noticia" id="fecha-noticia" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-12 text-center">Crear noticia</button>
</form>
<?php

    include('./DB.php');
    session_start();

    $conexion  = DB::conn();
    $sentencia = 'SELECT * FROM noticias';
    $consulta  = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);
    $consulta->execute();

?>
<div class="grid-container pt-4" id="ver-noticias">
    <?php while ($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <h4><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $row['texto']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $row['fecha']; ?></p>
            <img width="300" height="160" src="data:image/png; base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen']); ?>">
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php

    $consulta->closeCursor();
    $conexion = null;
    
?>
```

Comment: Graciass por su respuesta, lo probare cuando llegue a casa y le comento que tal va, saludos